# X29 Proximity Temperature sensor

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

What is the X29 Proximity (temperature) Sensor measuring? I'm on a 2013 MacBook Pro with Retina.

Answer (score 1):

The X29 Proximity Temperature sensor is used to monitor the heat that the CPU is producing, likely at different locations inside the computer, hence the word *proximity*.

Comment: How does this differ from the "CPU analog" and "CPU digital" sensors?

Comment: @lightbord My guess is that the name "proximity sensor" means that it measures CPU heat at different proximities.